# How to switch content access from local to remote group (and vice versa) seamlessly?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Question 1:
I am new to addressable. I have my online content that works fine but when I try to test locally to save up time , I get some errors..
cant' get to move addressable from "myCDN" group to "myLocal" group without breaking something. I end up with dependency or other other various errors.

As far as I know, all I have to do is grab all addressable from "myCDN" drag and drop them in "myLocal" and hit play. I suppose I am missing one or more step?

Should I run the analyze tool and fix dependency errors before doing so?

Question 2:
My group Bundle mode is set to: Pack together by label. Is is possible to build only one Label(the one I did some changes on)? if not, (assuming there is no dependencies between the labeled assets ) can I just re-upload one label pack and still expect it to work? I suppose the catalog should be re-uploaded as well?

Currently the only way I can get addressable to work after content has slightly been  changed, is to hit "build for content update" and then re-upload all the bundles.. I don't think this is intended to work like that right?

Comment: Consider splitting your question into 2 different threads. This is how SO format works : only one question per thread.

Comment: Oh I though they were both related to Addressable so I would put them together.. Well I'll be careful next time.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it, and it had nothing to do with groups or anything I described above. All I was doing was right, I knew it was suppose to be easy so it was something else:

// let's say I have 500 sprites locations, LoadResourceLocationsAsync loads each locations twice, 1 for the sprite, 2nd for the texture. Since I was not too familiar with the method, I went for a quick but bad solution of using the modulo operator to grab one in two. That "bad" solutions was working but whenever I was switching from remote to locale, there were errors with the locations... so basically it was trying to grab the textures instead of the sprites(and the error message was really misleading )... why does this happened, I have no idea. But came up with something more safe by using the property ResourceType to filter out the texture.

```
    static async Task LoadAllAnimSprite() {
            AnimManager.spriteAnimAsset = new List<Sprite>();
             var location = await Addressables.LoadResourceLocationsAsync(AnimManager.loadedLocations.animSprites_label.labelString).Task;  
              
            var location2 = location.Where(loc => loc.ResourceType == 
 typeof(Sprite)).ToList();
    
            
            var ttt = 0;
            foreach (var loc in location2)
            {
     
             //    if (ttt % 2 == 0) { <--- here is a really bad idea!
                 var obj = Addressables.LoadAssetAsync<Sprite>(loc);
                 await obj.Task;
                 AnimManager.spriteAnimAsset.Add(obj.Result );
    
           //    }
               // ttt++;
    
            }
            StartScreen.WaitForAnimDataInitialization_done = true;
    
    
        }
```

Thanks anyway.